# I create a table using bootstrap when in the print border the table is missing like not using a table

Tags: css

[enter image I created a table using a bootstrap css, but when the table print was lost. How to do when diprint table still has border?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ph6dt.png)

[his is the result of the display at the time will be printed. Has no border at all.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qh5Dt.png)

Comment: show your try code.

Comment: table {
    border:solid #000 !important;
    border-width:1px 0 0 1px !important;
}
th, td {
    border:solid #000 !important;
    border-width:0 1px 1px 0 !important;
}

you can orverride your css using !important

Comment: PLease before you seek help here read how to ask questions first. You can check it here https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve